# Execute Gradle command with Gradle task

Tags: android, gradle

I want to re-create verification-metadata.xml file with single click. I can create verification-metadata.xml with this command `./gradlew --write-verification-metadata sha256`. I try to create Gradle Task inside the build.gradle(app) and execute, but it didn't work

```
task verificationMeta(type: Exec) {
    workingDir "${rootDir}"
    commandLine './gradlew ', '--write', '-verification', '-metadata', ' sha256'
    doLast {
        println "Executed!"
    }
}
```

[rootDir](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:rootDir) is root directory of project.

This code gives me error;

```
Execution failed for task ':verificationMeta'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command './gradlew ''
```

How can I make it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you working on windows machine?

We had the problem that on windows machine you have to call gradlew.bat

Example:

```
task prodRepackage(type: Exec) {
    group = "Build"
    if (OperatingSystem.current().isWindows()) {
        executable "gradlew.bat"
        args "-Pprod", "bootJar"
    } else {
        executable "./gradlew"
        args "-Pprod", "bootJar"
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm working on linux/MacOS. What's the "group = Build" what's that for ?

Comment: this one is working: `task verificationMeta(type: Exec) {
    executable "./gradlew"
    args "--write-verification-metadata", "sha256"
    doLast {
        println "Executed!"
    }
}`

Comment: group = Build means that the task is in group task build (when you use e.g. IntelliJ you can see all gradle tasks with different groups (is only nice to have). If you set no group the task will appear under tasks "other"

Comment: This codes work for me Thanks to @Alexander . Another main problem is I was called task from build.gradle(app) this is wrong location it should be inside the build.gradle(root) or build.gradle. for android project

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround for the issue, I use .bat or .sh scripts to be executed as the following.

```
task executeCMD(type:Exec) {
  workingDir '.'
  commandLine 'test.bat'
     doLast {
         println "Executed!"
     }
 }
```

This, for example, will execute the test.bat script, which only has one line

`./gradlew --write-verification-metadata sha256`

if you're using Linux/macOS, you can replace the .bat with .sh.